# How can I index multiple array segments at once without a loop?

Tags: matlab

I want to change the value in column 2 based on the values in column 1 in one array (`main`), using a start and end index from another array (`conditions`).
In `conditions` column 1 holds the start index, column 2 the end index.

```
main = zeros(8, 2);
main(:, 1) = 1:8;
conditions = [2, 3; 6, 8]

main =

     1     0
     2     0
     3     0
     4     0
     5     0
     6     0
     7     0
     8     0

conditions =

     2     3
     6     8
```

I know how to do it using a loop (shown below), but am looking for a faster method.

```
for ii = 1:size(conditions, 1)
    main(main(:, 1) >= conditions(ii, 1) & main(:, 1) <= conditions(ii, 2), 2) = 1;
end

main =

     1     0
     2     1
     3     1
     4     0
     5     0
     6     1
     7     1
     8     1
```

Doing `main(main(:, 1) >= conditions(:, 1) & main(:, 1) <= conditions(:, 2), 2) = 1` results in the error `Matrix dimensions must agree`.

Is there a non-loop method?

Comment: Is the first column of `main` always just going to be the row index (i.e. `1:N`), or could it be something more complicated like `[1; 2; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 6; 6; 8]`?

Comment: It can be the latter.

Comment: And will these always be integer values? Will they always be sorted?

Comment: These can be unsorted floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is almost correct. If you transpose the `conditions`, then you'll be comparing a column of `main` with a row of `conditions`, leading to MATLAB doing implicit singleton expansion, giving a matrix output. This matrix can then be collapsed using `any`.

```matlab
main = zeros(8, 2);
main(:, 1) = 1:8;
conditions = [2, 3; 6, 8];

index = (main(:,1) >= conditions(:, 1).') & (main(:, 1) <= conditions(:, 2).');
index = any(index,2);
main(index,2) = 1;
```

(I've separated out the code into 3 lines for clarity, but of course they can all be a single line.)

---

Note that for versions of MATLAB prior to R2016b, this code won't work, you'll need to use `bsxfun` instead:

```matlab
index = bsxfun(@ge,main(:,1),conditions(:, 1).') & bsxfun(@le,main(:, 1),conditions(:, 2).');
```

Comment: Looks like this also works for the more general case of unsorted floats mentioned in the comments (tested with `main = [rand(8, 1) zeros(8, 1)]; conditions = [0.1 0.3; 0.7 1];`).

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** This is a solution for integers only as the original question only presented the integer case.

First, figure out how many elements there are included in the interval

```
dCon = diff(conditions,[],2)+1;
```

Then construct an increasing sequence of indexes to the maximum number of elements (this list would be enormous for the float case, and thus this solution does not, feasibly/efficiently, extend to floats)

```
idx0 = repmat(1:max(dCon),length(dCon),1);
```

Cap off the indexes that are too large

```
idx0(idx0>dCon)=1;
```

Now add the starting point

```
idx = idx0 + conditions(:,1)-1;
```

now `idx` contains all the numbers you want to change. Use `ismember` to find all elements in `main` and change them to `1`.

```
main(ismember(main(:,1),idx(:)),2)=1;
```

**EDIT:** This is the full example with the vector from Gnovice in the comments

```
main = zeros(10, 2);
main(:, 1) = [1; 2; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 6; 6; 8];
conditions = [2, 3; 6, 8]
dCon = diff(conditions,[],2)+1;
idx0 = repmat(1:max(dCon),length(dCon),1);
idx0(idx0>dCon)=1;
idx = idx0 + conditions(:,1)-1;
main(ismember(main(:,1),idx(:)),2)=1;
```

Comment: Nice solution! This *might* be faster for very large `main`, because the intermediate matrices are smaller than in my solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work for the general case where the values are unsorted floats (tested with `main = [rand(8, 1) zeros(8, 1)]; conditions = [0.1 0.3; 0.7 1];`).

Comment: You are absolutely right @gnovice, the expansion `repmat(1:max(dCon),length(dCon),1);` only covers integers - and is infeasible to use for floats. It should, however, work for unsorted integers.